# Use Facebook API to search for links in posts

Tags: php, facebook, api, search

Hey, I was wondering if it is possible to search Facebook using their API for a given URL. I am trying to find how many people are mentioning a given link.
An example of what I am trying to achieve is the Tweetmeme url_info request but for Facebook. The Tweetmeme API returns an array of imformation about a given link, such as frequency used and last tweeted.
If anyone knows of a Facebook alternative, it would be greatly appreciated. I have a look throught their API wiki but can't find any solutions.

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While researching the answer from Vance Lucas I came accross the FQL equivilent @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat

```
$facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="MY_URL"');
```

This FQL Statment returns the "Share Count", "Link Count", "Comment Count" and "Total Count".

Answer (score 5):

I recently stumblued upon this hidden gem when building an SEO tool:

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

It's an old API, but you can confirm the counts are up-to-date by checking this against their new Graph API that only gives you the total count:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://stackoverflow.com/
```

Comment: You are my absolute hero. The Graph search won't be available on December 25th, and this will allow us to continue monitoring our posts!

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Graph API Overview page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) of the Facebook Developers documentation, under the subheading "Searching". It indicates you can use the Graph API to search all public posts for a given query:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=<your_url_here>&type=post
```

(Be sure to URL-encode your URL first.)

This will retrieve a JSON array containing mentions of your URL. It appears not to provide any metadata about the search, but is rather a paginated list of search results, so you'd have to build the metadata yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the APIs that I originally tried to use, but the results seem to be limited in what they can do. Thanks Anyway

Comment: This method returns some of the most wildly inaccurate results (even if you put a URI in there which is...I don't know...unique!) that I've ever seen from a "search" in all my life and career as a web developer. It is almost a complete waste for Facebook to have this method. For posts. That said, it works quite well for pages.

Comment: The Facebook API has changed so much in three years that I'm a bit stunned the endpoint even *functions* as I originally described.